# Output PHP array as PHP code, formatted

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file with a HUGE array that goes multiple dimensions deep and looks a bit like this.

```
$array = array(
   'all_tools' => array(
       'title' => 'Tools',
       'help' => 'Help with tools'
   ),
   'addcode' => array(
       'title' => 'Add Code',
       'help' => 'Add code help'
   ),
   'editcode' => array(
       'title' => 'Edit Code',
       'help' => 'Edit code help'
   )
);
```

Apparently this is not readable enough and I've been asked to convert this array to the following format.

```
$array['all_tools']['title'] = 'Tools';
$array['all_tools']['help'] = 'Help with tools';

$array['addcode']['title'] = 'Add Code';
$array['addcode']['help'] = 'Add code help';

$array['editcode']['title'] = 'Edit Code';
$array['editcode']['help'] = 'Edit code help';
```

It is the same array, but I need to structure it like this. This will take hours to do by hand because this file is enormous. Does anyone know of a PHP function that will print the contents of a multi-dimensional array the way this way?

Edit:
I would like a little more information. The array I am working on has some variation in how many arrays may be nested in each key. I need a solution that can go as many levels deep as necessary and dynamically knows when to stop when it bumps into a string rather than an array.

Comment: strange request considering the first one really is much easier to read than the way you've been asked to convert to.

Comment: In PHP the difference may be small, but when I coded an array in the second format in JavaScript (with several thousand entries total), it took a full minute to run - whereas the first format ended up running instantly. Bosses like yours makes me glad I'm my own :p

Comment: I went through all of this already. I originally wrote the file using nested arrays as in my first example and it has grown over the years, but now my co-workers are having to edit it. Some of us prefer decent PHP editing software that helps catch tiny discrepancies in our code and some of us don't. Parse errors that occur as a result of editing this file are becoming a problem. So in the spirit of compromise, we are going to strain PHP a little bit to make the code more editable for more of us. I agree that it's a pain, but not my call.

Answer (score 3):

This will spit out a text file you can copy and paste into your code:

```
foreach($array as $first_level_key => $value){
    foreach($value as $sub_key => $sub_value){
        echo "\$array['".$first_level_key."']['".$sub_key."'] = '$sub_value'; \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

from the php.net manual for [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php#92065)

```
<?php
function recursive_print ($varname, $varval) {
  if (! is_array($varval)):
    print $varname . ' = ' . var_export($varval, true) . ";<br>\n";
  else:
    print $varname . " = array();<br>\n";
    foreach ($varval as $key => $val):
      recursive_print ($varname . "[" . var_export($key, true) . "]", $val);
    endforeach;
  endif;
}
?>
```

> If your output is to a text file and not an HTML page, remove the
> <br>s.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can output the PHP variable as directly consumable code.

1. [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) Just like `var_dump`/`print_r`, you can use `var_export` to just output the array as consumable(parsable) php code.
2. `json_encode` you can output the array to `JSON` encoded format, which will be consumable by not only the `PHP` language, but also most of the other language since `JSON` is a language agnostic format.
3. [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) + `unserialize`
4. Use your own function/method to generate the output `php` string.